# $u_1\vee u_2\vee u_3\vee\dots\vee u_m = u$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Let $u\neq 0$ be any element of Boolean Algebra. Let $u_1,u_2,u_3,\dots,u_m$ be all atoms in $A$ such that $u_1\leq u,u_2 \leq u,\dots, u_m\leq u$.
Prove that $u_1\vee u_2\vee u_3\vee\dots\vee u_m = u$.

Here '$\vee$' denotes join of a lattice. I tried to prove the equality by proving LHS $\leq$ RHS AND RHS $\leq$ LHS, so LHS $=$ RHS. Proving from right to left was simple. Since $u_1\leq u, u_2\leq u,\dots,u_m\leq u$, we can say that $$u_1+u_2+u_3+\dots+u_m\leq \underbrace{u+u+\dots+u}_{m\text{ times}} = u$$ (since closed under Boolean algebra). But I am not able to prove from left to right.

Please help me with a complete solution if possible, since I am beginner in this course.

Comment: Your assertion will not be true in general, a counterexample being the direct product between the boolean algebra structure on the ordered set $\{0, 1\}$ and any nontrivial boolean algebra with *no* atoms (an example of the latter structure is for instance the algebra generated by the left-closed half-open intervals on $\mathbb{R}$). The assertion will hold though under the additional assumption that the principal ideal $(a]$ is an *Artinian* ordered set ($a$ being the fixed element you are attempting to decompose as a disjunction of atoms).

Comment: slight correction in the above: take the boolean algebra $\mathscr{P}(\{0, 1\})$ as the first factor in the suggested direct product (my bad). This is a lattice with just two atoms (which also happen to be coatoms).

Comment: But this is given as a prove question to us.

Comment: Most likely one of two things have occurred: 1) either the person responsible with formulating the problem made an omission of necessary additional conditions or 2) it was you perhaps who omitted such conditions. Regardless, you can prove the result by strengthening the set of hypotheses. The simplest way of doing so is to consider the particular case when your boolean algebra is *finite*. A somewhat more sophisticated additional assumption would be that the principal ideal $(a]=(\leftarrow, a]_R$ is finite, where by $R$ I am symbolising the underlying order relation.

Comment: Let me try to give you a hint of how to prove the statement given the hypothesis that there are only finitely many elements less than $a$: define $b$ to be the disjunction of all the atoms under $a$, so that clearly $b \leqslant_R a$. Then consider the *relative* complement $c\colon=a \setminus b=a \wedge \overline{b}$. Your goal is to prove that $c=0_A$, so as to infer that $a \leqslant_R b$. Assuming that $c \neq 0_A$ would mean that the interval $(0_A, c]_R$ is nonempty and finite, therefore having a minimal element $t$, which is necessarily an atom of $A$ under $a$. Can you continue?